# How do I safely handle an image url submission that doesn't have a file extension on the end of it?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a system that uses Laravel Media Library to store images from URLs, and not uploaded images.  In testing I'm using `$faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480)` to generate a random url. On the controller I have a helper function that gets a file extension from an image url to help with creating a filename to be stored:

**Helper**

```
function getFileExtensionFromImgPath($image_path)
{


    $typeString = null;
    $typeInt = exif_imagetype($image_path);

    //dd($typeInt);

    switch($typeInt) {
        case IMG_GIF:
        $typeString = 'gif';
        break;
        case IMG_JPG:
        $typeString = 'jpg';
        break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $typeString = 'jpeg';
        break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $typeString = 'png';
        break;
        case IMG_WBMP:
        $typeString = 'wbmp';
        break;
        case IMG_XPM:
        $typeString = 'xpm';
        break;
        default: 
        $typeString = 'unknown';
    }

    return $typeString;
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $imgPath = $request->input('img_path');
    if (!empty($imgPath)) {

        //Create filename

        $filename = time() . '_' . $post->slug . "." . getFileExtensionFromImgPath($imgPath);

        dd($filename);

        // Store in Laravel media manager
        $post->addMediaFromUrl($imgPath)->usingFileName($filename)->toMediaCollection('post_thumbnail');

    }
    //dd($post->getFirstMedia('post_thumbnail')->getPath());
    return new PostResource($post);
}
```

The problem I keep having is the image that `$faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480)` doesn't generate a url with an extension like JPG or PNG: `http://lorempixel.com/800/400/cats/Faker/` which during testing gives me a

> ErrorException: exif_imagetype(): Read error!

How do I safely handle an image url submission that doesn't have a file extension on the end of it?

*Edit*

I'm looking for help with my helper function to determine whether or not a link that doesn't have a file extension is an image. When I set the image passed through the request to have a file extension like jpg, png, the tests succeed. I'm trying to figure out a use case when a url link doesn't have a file extension.

Comment: Unless you know that `lorempixel.com` always returns JPEGs, the only way to do it is to download the image and analyse the format (e.g. using the POSIX `file` command, or ImageMagick `identify` command, or equivalently through the PHP extension [`Imagick::identifyImage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyimage.php)).

Comment: Can you show me an example using `Imagick::identifyImage`. I tried `$image = new Imagick($real_location); 

        dd($image);` and am just getting a 500

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out if your users are going to be passing URLs of existing images, or if they are going to be actually uploading files, your controller code leads me to believe the latter.

I think your controller code may be just fine it's really your test setup that needs work, currently you are are passing a URL to the controller and then trying to treat it as an actual file, but in production it'll actually receive a real file which will be an instance of  Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.

Therefore, in your test you should be using `UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg')` instead of the `$faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480)`

You can change the file extension to suit your needs, or something like `UploadedFile::fake()->image($faker->randomElement(['avatar.jpg', 'avatar.png', 'avatar.gif', 'avatar.bmp',]))`

Here's the full Laravel Docs on testing File Uploads:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#testing-file-uploads

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I should've been clearer the image URL's will be submitted by links and not uploaded. When I use something like `avatar.jpg` the tests succeeds, but the problem is a link of an image might be submitted without an extension. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Did I read this wrong or do you want to support both cases where there can be either a real image uploaded or a URL to an existing image? Or do you only want to handle image URLs?

Comment: Sorry, I must've said it wrong. I am just supporting getting an URL of an existing image from the web.